# s3cmd reads configuration file but claims it doesn't exist

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, s3cmd, ceph

I'm using `s3cmd` to access the Ceph storage provided by my cloud provider. I created a minimal `.s3cfg` file on my VM to do so. When I try to list buckets, it claims that it can't find the configuration file despite `--debug` output showing that it's parsing it:

```
$ s3cmd ls --debug
DEBUG: s3cmd version 1.6.1
DEBUG: ConfigParser: Reading file '/home/ubuntu/.s3cfg'
DEBUG: ConfigParser: access_key->...-3_chars...
DEBUG: ConfigParser: secret_key->...-3_chars...
DEBUG: ConfigParser: enable_multipart->True
DEBUG: ConfigParser: host_base->storage.datacentred.io
DEBUG: ConfigParser: host_bucket->%(bucket)s.storage.datacentred.io
DEBUG: ConfigParser: use_https->True
ERROR: /home/ubuntu/.s3cfg: None
ERROR: Configuration file not available.
ERROR: Consider using --configure parameter to create one.
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is there a key property that is missing that would make `s3cmd` believe the file doesn't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prior line `/home/ubuntu/.s3cfg: None`, says there is some error parsing your configuration file. The `None` unfortunately means whatever the error was doesn't have a nice string to display :-(.

Here's the relevant block of `s3cmd` source:

```
try: 
    cfg = Config(options.config, options.access_key, options.secret_key, options.access_token)
except IOError, e:
    if options.run_configure:
        cfg = Config()
    else:
        error(u"%s: %s"  % (options.config, e.strerror))
        error(u"Configuration file not available.")
```

Comment: Indeed. I filed a bug here: https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/903 and it appears that my issue is due to missing `secret_key` and `access_key` values and is a duplicate of: https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/834

Thanks for highlighting the relevant part of the code, it might help fix this issue.

Comment: approve this answer then? I'd patch upstream for you, but they note they have a rewrite of that code in process.